Android internal testing via play.google.com isn't working
I am trying to test auto app updates. And for that, I read that I have to test it via internal testing.
I have followed all the steps of the tutorials that I have come across. In the end, I get a link on pressing "How testers join your test" with this format:
https://play.google.com/apps/internaltest/4701544997813299650
On clicking this, I get the following image:

Which makes me wonder: how am I supposed to get new internal testing updates?
According to the below screenshot, I am sharing an internal testing app, but I cannot see/download it.

Could anyone help me pinpoint what I am missing. Thanks
This is what Ive tried:

Developer mode on the phone's play store
Internal app sharing on phone's play store
Tester mail on phone's play store is same as in internal tester of play.google.com
Removed, re added testers
Cleared cached, restarted, re enabled first 2 steps on phone


click on the link that says "download it on Google Play" from your first screenshot above and you can install the app from there for the first time (uninstall previous version from phone before that). now, publish new version to internal test track and you will get popup of in-app update when you open the app. Hope this helps.

Not getting such popup. Thanks for the suggestion.

Can you post the code you're using for in-app update?
